# Find relative path of file from another file with path string

Tags: javascript, path

I'm trying to figure out a way to compare two absolute(ish!) file locations and return the relative path from one to another in the shortest way possible.

```js
/*
Example 1:
..\root\folder\subFolder\myCurrent.file
..\root\folder\subFolder\img\myTarget.image

Expected result:
.\img\myTarget.image

Example 2:
..\root\folder\subFolder\myCurrent.file
..\root\folder\otherSubFolder\img\myTarget.image

Expected result:
..\otherSubFolder\img\myTarget.image

Example 3:
..\root\folder\subFolder\myCurrent.file
..\root\folder\subFolder\myTarget.image

Expected result:
myTarget.image
*/
```

I tried to split the paths to arrays and compare length and values, but it turned out to be a complete mess and I didn't even manage to do it yet...

```js
const currentFilePath = activepath.split('\\')
const currentDir = currentFilePath[currentFilePath.indexOf(currentFilePath[currentFilePath.length - 2])];
const targetFilePath = file.path.split('\\');
const targetDir = targetFilePath[targetFilePath.indexOf(targetFilePath[targetFilePath.length - 2])];
const currentFileDepth = currentFilePath.length;
// and so on...
```

I would like a decent, clean way to figure this out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For node.js, there's a [built-in](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to) for this:

```
let path = require('path').win32;

r = path.relative(
    "..\\root\\folder\\subFolder\\myCurrent.file",
    "..\\root\\folder\\subFolder\\img\\myTarget.image");

console.log(r) // ..\img\myTarget.image
```

For browsers, google around for a port, or just grab [the source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/path.js#L436), which is small and transparent.

`path.relative` expects the first argument to be a directory, if it's a file name, you have to obtain the directory first:

```
let path = require('path').win32;

r = path.relative(
    path.dirname("..\\root\\folder\\subFolder\\myCurrent.file"),
    "..\\root\\folder\\subFolder\\img\\myTarget.image");

console.log(r) // img\myTarget.image
```

Comment: Just tried that, and it deserved the upvote I gave you. However, as depicted in your snippet, the function returns with a string starting in "..\", but imagine if this is the path to an image that I would insert as <img>'s src... it would broke. Why is it different than the expected ".\" ?

Comment: Why is the doc so few detailed about this ? Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 2):

You could split both paths, then get the unique components from both arrays using `.filter()`. Then grab the unique components pertaining to the parts of the second path by using `.filter()` again and finally using `.join('\\')` to create your result:

```js
const comparePaths = (a, b) => {
  const a_parts = a.split('\\');
  const b_parts = b.split('\\');
  const arr = [...a_parts, ...b_parts];
  const diffs = arr.filter(item => arr.indexOf(item) === arr.lastIndexOf(item));
  let path_parts = diffs.filter(part => b_parts.includes(part));
  const res = ".".repeat(path_parts.length && path_parts.length-1 || 0) +'\\'+ path_parts.join('\\');
  return res;
}

console.log(comparePaths("..\\root\\folder\\subFolder\\myCurrent.file",
"..\\root\\folder\\subFolder\\img\\myTarget.image"));

console.log(comparePaths("..\\root\\folder\\subFolder\\myCurrent.file",
"..\\root\\folder\\otherSubFolder\\img\\myTarget.image"));

console.log(comparePaths("..\\foo\\bar\\foobar.js",
"..\\foo\\bar\\foobar.js"));
```

Comment: Sorry, but the first and third logs are wrong regarding what I'm trying to achieve. They should respectively start by '.\' and '' instead of '..\' for both. Those two paths would not resolve properly.

Comment: So your expected output for both should start with ```.\```? Because that isn't what's written in the question

Comment: The expected output should be a valid file system path linking the current file to the target file. I provided another example so you can spot the difference.